# ¿Por qué el fondo no ocupa toda la altura de la página?

Tags: html, css

Básicamente el problema es qué quiero hacer un fondo con degradado para que se vea bonita mi pagina pero al utilizar el comando/estilo:

```css
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
```

Se ve horrible. aquí dejo una foto de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y un ejemplo del código:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
}
```

```html
<h1>Proyecto Personal</h1>
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(71,118,230,1) 0%, rgba(142,84,233,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html><body>sad<body><html>
```

Es que el problema creo que se debe a que no le específicas la cantidad que debe tener cada color, por que si pones un `50%` a cada color se mira de una manera horrenda. Entonces lo mejor que puedes hacer es especificarle el porcentaje que quieres que cada color tenga y con el `deg` puedes especificar a que dirección debe ir el degradado. Aunque puede que también sea por alguna versión de navegador(Que lo dudo mucho en este caso) así que lo ideal sería que usaras prefijos:

```css
body{
  background: rgb(71,118,230);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(71,118,230,1) 0%, rgba(142,84,233,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(71,118,230,1) 0%, rgba(142,84,233,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(71,118,230,1) 0%, rgba(142,84,233,1) 100%);
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. Has cambiado el gradiente para que sea horizontal en lugar de vertical. Eso hace que se vea mejor pero no soluciona el problema real que es que, como indica otros usuario, el `body` no tiene altura y por eso se ve así.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Bueno, creo que tienes razón:/, de cualquier manera le dije que puede cambiar la dirección del gradiente con `deg`, si la respuesta no le es útil, procederé a eliminarla.

Answer (score 1):

Buen Día.

Lo único que te falto fue colocar el "height" en unidades de viewport coloca el código CSS de la siguiente forma y te funcionará al 100%:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
}
```

Yo completaría el código del CSS del body de la siguiente forma, lo hago como buena práctica:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```